# Retrieving other side of a relationship in a middle-man object

Tags: many-to-many, symfony, doctrine-orm

Sorry if the title doesn't make much sense, if you have a suggestion on a more accurate description of my problem, please suggest it.

I'm working on a Symfony 2 application and I have User objects which must relate to another User, simple use case being friends but there are more complex cases as well. Originally I had a simple many to many relationship between users and life was grand.

Now I need to track meta data on the relationship itself between the two users, e.g:

- when the relationship was requested
- when it was accepted
- when it ended
- if it ended, are there blocks to prevent this relationship being reopened
- etc.

I've done a fair bit of research and it seems with Doctrine I cannot have meta data on the relations themselves because they are not entities. It was suggested I use a middle man object, so Users have a many-to-many relationship with a Friendship object. The friendship object contains the meta dat and references to the two users.

Now onto my problem, if I have this friendship object how do I retrieve the other side of it? Do I have a function which I pass the user I know so I get the other user? One way I've thought of implementing this is below, but it seems to me there should be another way

```
$user = $this->getCurrentUser();
$friends = array();
foreach($user->getFriends() as $friendship)
{
    $friends[] = $friendship->not($user); // return the user we dont have
}
```

and $friendship->not() being:

```
public function not($user)
{
    return $this->user1===$user ? $this->user2 : $this->user1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved a friendship problem a couple of years ago. I don't remember all the details, but I'll try to tell you what I remember.

First of all, look at this [section](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional), which says:

> Real many-to-many associations are less common. [...]
>
> Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes.

So, I had the `User` and `Friendship` entities, which were mapped to the `user` and `friendship` tables. The latter looked something like this:

```
| friendship   |
+--------------+
| from_id      |
| to_id        |
| requested_at |
| accepted_at  | ← if this is not null, then it was accepted
```

Since I prefer to keep things simple, my `User` entities weren't aware of the `Friendship` entities — that is, the `Friendship` class referenced the `User` class in the unidirectional manner. What this means in your case is that you can't get a list of friends from the `User` class. You, of course, can implement it the way that allows you to do it.

Then, I had this `FriendshipService` class (the [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) pattern) which had a method like `findBy(User $user)`, which would make a database request like “find all friendships where `from` equals `$user` or `to` equals `$user`”. (Probably there was something else to that query, but I can't remember.) After you have a set of friendships from the database, iterating over it and listing all the friends is trivial. You can get the other side of a friendship like this:

```
$otherSide = 
    $friendship->getFrom() == $currentUser ? 
    $friendship->getTo() : 
    $friendship->getFrom();
```

Comment: Thanks elnur, I've discussed it with a few others and referenced your post, I think I will move in this direction.

Comment: Could you specify which way would allow to get the Friends from the User class?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only storing references, you could maintain a parallel array of users and relationships.

```
$user = $this->getCurrentUser();
$friends[] = $user->getFriends();
$friendships[] = $user->getFriendships();
```

Where friends[0] has relationship friendship[0] with $user.

This is a pretty standard tradeoff of space for speed, and will of course require the extra steps on insert/delete etc.

If you're storing objects and not references, this could use up a lot of space very fast though, and you'd be better off maintaining friendships as a completely separate list and searching for all friendships that contain $user.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that does provide some insight. I do need to store objects to keep track of all the meta data (and the list of meta data will likely grow), but it sounds like a good idea to move that into a separate relation.